# NHibernate Find by Example

Tags: nhibernate

In NHibernate, Is it possible to do a look up based on an entity passed?

I would like to pass an object from the ui and do a look up based on its values instead of having multiple methods for each possible variation.

For example if I pass a user with the firstname 'John', I'd like to return all users with that firstname.

Any hints much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Find by example method in Nhibernate.
Here :

```
var user=new User();
user.Firstname="John";
var criteria=session.CreateCriteria(typeof(User)).Add(Example.Create(user));
```

Example is a special kind of expression that builds criterion based on provided entity.